# Undefined Reference Error When Trying to Build Project With .C and .CPP Files Using CLion

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors, clion, undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile a MonteCarlo Simulator program (https://www.stat.washington.edu/thompson/Genepi/Mcleeps.shtml).

This is the error I'm getting when I try to build the project:

```
CMakeFiles\MonteCarlo.dir/objects.a(ne_classes.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/Michael/CLionProjects/MonteCarlo/ne_classes.cpp:90: undefined reference > to `setall(long, long)'
C:/Users/Michael/CLionProjects/MonteCarlo/ne_classes.cpp:182: undefined reference > to `setall(long, long)'
C:/Users/Michael/CLionProjects/MonteCarlo/ne_classes.cpp:312: undefined 
reference to `getsd(long*, long*)'
CMakeFiles\MonteCarlo.dir/objects.a(ne_classes.cpp.obj): In function 
`Z21draw_folded_asin_normddiiiPid':
C:/Users/Michael/CLionProjects/MonteCarlo/ne_classes.cpp:1230: undefined 
reference to `gennor(float, float)'
C:/Users/Michael/CLionProjects/MonteCarlo/ne_classes.cpp:1236: undefined 
reference to `ranf()'
CMakeFiles\MonteCarlo.dir/objects.a(ne_classes.cpp.obj): In function 
`Z10RealizeNewP10LatentInfoP8GeneInfoP7LogProbi':
C:/Users/Michael/CLionProjects/MonteCarlo/ne_classes.cpp:1990: undefined 
reference to `gennor(float, float)'
CMakeFiles\MonteCarlo.dir/objects.a(ne_classes.cpp.obj): In function 
`Z7uniformii':
C:/Users/Michael/CLionProjects/MonteCarlo/ne_classes.cpp:2111: undefined 
reference to `ignuin(long, long)'
CMakeFiles\MonteCarlo.dir/objects.a(ranlib.c.obj): In function `setgmn':
C:/Users/Michael/CLionProjects/MonteCarlo/ranlib.c:1468: undefined reference 
to `spofa'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [MonteCarlo.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MonteCarlo.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MonteCarlo.dir/rule] Error 2
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(MonteCarlo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_executable(MonteCarlo ne_classes.cpp com.c ranlib.c linpack.c 
ne_headers.h ranlib.h)
```

`ne_classes.cpp` contains the main function

After trying to google this problem I've found that this is probably due to the fact I'm using a different version of g++ to compile the program. Also this has something to do with linking problems between .c and .cpp files. However I still have no idea how to use a different version of g++ to compile or how the linking problem is caused. It is all a little above me and I've spent hours already trying to get this problem to build so here I am, asking this question, as my last resort.

I can post the contents of each file if you need me to or you can download them yourself from the website I linked above.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a declaration and definition for each function mentioned in the errors? Do you have warnings enabled? Are C files included properly with `extern "C" {}`?

Comment: BTW. over 2000 is quite a lot of lines for one file...

Comment: I did not write the code so I'll do my best here to try and answer your questions. One of the functions mentioned in the error is `ignuin`. The function is being called in `ne_classes.cpp` and I found that it is declared in `ne_headers.h` like this `GLOB long ignuin(long a, long n);` Im not sure if C files are properly included with `extern "C" {}`. There is a `#define UN_EXTERN` at the top of the `ne_classes.cpp` file. Not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you find where this function is defined? Where is it's body, the instructions that are to be called? That is the most common source of 'undefined reference' errors. `GLOB` is probably some sort of macro, you could try to find it as well. Have you added all source files (.cpp, .c) to CMake?

Comment: `ignuin` seems to be defined in `ranlib.c`

static long ignuin,ign,maxnow,range,ranp1;

    if(!(low > high)) goto S10;
    fputs(" low > high in ignuin - ABORT",stderr);
    exit(1);

    S10:
    range = high-low;
    if(!(range > maxnum)) goto S20;
    fputs(" high - low too large in ignuin - ABORT",stderr);
    exit(1);

    S20:
    if(!(low == high)) goto S30;
    ignuin = low;
    return ignuin;


Im so sorry I cannot figure out how to format it properly so that its readable

Comment: And yes all the source files have been added to cmake

Comment: looking at all the `goto` statements and the missing 'extern C' statements for the C header files, I would suggest the referenced code need a major re-design

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build the project by adding `extern "C" {#include "ranlib.h"}` to the `#include "ranlib.h"` in the `ne_headers.h` file

Comment: I was about to write comment about `extern "C"`. Good catch :)